# Delivering a web page in HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, https, cassini

I have an ASP.NET website running on Cassini web server.  This website will not be published on the internet but will only be used for demonstration purposes.

Now, I want to deliver the log-in page using HTTPS instead of HTTP.  How can this be done please?

I have tried adding the following to the web.config file but it is giving me an error:

```
<secureWebPages enabled="true">
    <file path="LogIn.aspx" />
  </secureWebPages>
```

This code was inserted right after the `connectionString` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassini does not support HTTPS.

Instead, you can use IIS or IIS Express, which do.

Note that you will also need a certificate trusted by the browser.

Comment: How can this be done in IIS then?  I know how to set up the website in IIS.  I only need to know how to make a page in HTTPS.

Comment: Googles top two hits are the instructions for IIS 7 and IIS 6, and there probably is a Q around here somewhere that repeats it on SO: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+configure+ssl+in+iis&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=&safe=images